# Mapping Output Tensor of Residual/Convolutional Block to Fully Connected Layer without Flattening Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensor

i am implementing a Deep Learning model to learn to classify between 10,000 classes.

The architecture is the model is it takes (100, 100, 4) image into a 4 block residual network which outputs a (100, 100, 64) tensor. this has a output layer of dimension of (10000, ).

is there any way to map (100, 100, 64) layer to output of (10000, ) nodes without flattening it ?

Additional Information :

The model i am talking about is one of two models proposed in the published Paper called "Teaching Robots to Draw" [link here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Teaching-Robots-To-Draw-Kotani-Tellex/83eea8ec6550e9e797244fc2c0c5c81bdc43ceb2).

i had trouble trying to build this model (know as Global Model in paper) because flattened (100, 100, 64) tensor fully connected layer to (10000, ) would have too many parameters. when asked about this to authors of the paper they suggested the following  :

*You would not need a maxpool layer or even flatten the model output.
Instead what you should do is to prepare 1 FC layer that maps 64-D vector to 1-D, and apply it to every cell of the final output of resnet, which has size of (N, 100, 100, 64).
Now you convert this huge tensor of (N, 100, 100, 64) to (N, 100, 100, 1) with this single FC layer*

this what i was able to implement in keras :

```
inp = Input(shape=(inp_img_dim))
x_a = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(inp)
x_a = res_block_16(x_a)
x_a = res_block_16_1(x_a)
x_a = res_block_32(x_a)
x_a = res_block_64(x_a) # outputs a 100x100x64 layer 
# iterate over batch_size dimension 
out = tf.map_fn(func_map, elems = x_a, fn_output_signature=tf.float32) 
# create model
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
# summarize model
model.summary()
```

func_map function takes each (100, 100, 64) tensor from the batch, flattens it to (10000, 64) dimension tensor and iterates over the 0th dimension, slicing (1, 64) D tensor which are mapped to (1, ) D tensor using a fully connected layer. each of the outputs are stored in list and are converted back to a tensor. like this:

```
# layer to map 64 D to 1D
input_ = Input(shape=64)
output_ = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(input_)
map_layer = Model(input_, output_)

# map intermediate tensor 10000x64 to 10000
def func_map(tensor):
  global map_layer
  # tensor = tensor[0]
  tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, (10000, 64))
  inter_st = []
  for i in range(0,10000):
    inter = tf.slice(tensor, [i, 0], [0, 64])
    # print(inter.shape)
    inter_ = map_layer(inter)
    inter_st.append(inter_)
    # break
    print(len(inter_st))
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.asarray(inter_st), dtype=tf.float32) # redundant conversion,
```

this model this takes forever to build and i am quite sure that this is not the most effective way to achieve this.

So, any ideas or even pointers in right directions are appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is really simple, i was able to get a reply from the authors for the paper itself. i was going to delete this question but realized that someone might need this( i have wasted months on this problem). so i am posting it here.

in keras you can directly map a 3D tensor such as (100, 100, 64) to a dense layer.

code :

```
inp = Input(shape=(inp_img_dim))
x_a = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(inp)
x_a = res_block_16(x_a)
x_a = res_block_16_1(x_a)
x_a = res_block_32(x_a)
x_a = res_block_64(x_a)
# some magic here
out = Dense(1, activation="softmax")(x_a)
out = Flatten()(out)
# create model
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
# summarize model
model.summary()
```

i am not sure how this is working, but if i get to know how it is working internally i will definitely do a follow up post.

sorry to anyone who spent their valuable time on this question, any suggestions are still welcome!

thank you.